# how to split nested list containing strings with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list:

```
lst=['A','B',['ABB','ADE'],'Z','!@#',['UU','II']]
```

how to deal with `['ABB','ADE']`, `['UU','II']`so that I got:

```
lst=['A','B','ABB','ADE','Z','!@#','UU','II']
```

tried many methods but not working. The order should NOT be the changed.

Comment: i.e. `lst = list(flatten(lst))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst=['A','B',['ABB','ADE'],'Z','!@#',['UU','II']]
new_list = []
for item in lst:
    new_list.extend(item)
print(new_list)
```